# initsip() crashes with a corrupted stack

Tags: python, boost-python, python-sip

When getting a pointer to the sip API:

```
sip_API = reinterpret_cast<const sipAPIDef*>(
    PyCapsule_Import("sip._C_API", 0));
```

a crash is reported in `initsip()`.

Also, when constructing C++ classes using boost.Python, a strange error is returned:

```
TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'NoneType'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these problems are caused by linking against a different version of python than sip/boost are compiled with.